# How to make a thread bind only a core when using Intel MKL?

Tags: intel-mkl

I want to use threaded mkl to make matrix multiplication. I am try to use 8 threads.My cpu has 8 cores and each core has two logistical cores. I do not know whether the intel mkl will bind each thread to only one core?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the operating system and is a task that the operating system will deal with. So, an answer would depend on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MKL will detect the number of physical cores available in your system and use them all. If you want to use 8 threads, you can set up the environment variable using export MKL_NUM_THREADS=8. Also, Intel recommends to use the number of threads equal to the number of physical cores not logical cores.